# Есть в библиотеке libgdx классы реализующие экранный контролер?

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть ли в библиотеке libgdx классы реализующие экранный контроллер, идеально было бы "рычажок в круге"?

P.S. Под идее стандартный ввод через клавиши вроде есть. Вот и мысли, нет ли чего нибуд работающего через тач-скрин.

Answer (score 0):

Готовой реализации нет, но сделать его довольно просто используя тот же самый `InputProcessor`